making a scrollable frame look natural in tkinter environment
What I'm longing for
I'm creating a scrollable frame. It is actually a frame containing a scrollbar and a canvas in which is another frame. This way, the frame inside the canvas can be scrolled using the scrollbar.
You can see here a "vertical scrolled frame" that works.
I would like it to look like it is just a frame with a scrollbar on the left (and able to scroll), using it this way:
root = tkinter.Tk()
scroll_frame = ScrollFrame(root)

for i in range(100):
   ttk.Button(scroll_frame, text=f"Button {i}").pack()

scroll_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()

Obviously, this is not possible in the example I gave because the buttons will be packed in the container frame, that is not scrollable. We have to do this instead:
ttk.Button(scroll_frame.interior, text=...)

And the ScrollFrame isn't anymore similar to tkinter widgets...
What I've thought about

My first idea was to catch, like an event, the attribution of a ScrollFrame as a master and give the interior frame instead; but I haven't found any way to do this.

Also, I inversed the roles: ScrollFrame() returns the interior frame, and the container frame is ScrollFrame().container. The ScrollFrame being now the interior frame, the problem is that I have to write this:
scroll_frame = ScrollFrame()
...
scroll_frame.container.pack()   #doesn't look natural

To solve this issue, I went with two ideas :

put that in ScrollFrame.__init__:

self.pack  = self.pack_configure  = container.pack
self.grid  = self.grid_configure  = container.grid
self.place = self.place_configure = container.place

But this may be source of problems, because there is much stuff linked with pack, grid and place, so I also have to add everything around, like pack_forget, maybe packinfo, grid_forget etc. and I may not include them all.

Then I discovered the <Map> event and thought: "Oh! This is easy, I'm going to do something like this :"

def on_map(event):
   container.tk.call((event.geometry_manager, "configure", container._w) + event.options)

self.bind("<Map>", on_map)

Unfortunately, I have not found any way to get information about how the event was called. And if the grid method is called with some arguments, I want the container to be displayed with grid and these arguments, not with pack or anything else...
Please help !
Is what I want to do such a bad idea?
Is there a way to do this properly?

Every design has its limitations or constraints, so live with it if you cannot find a better way.

There is another interesting approach, but might be harder to use

@DanyaK this seems quit similar to the customtkinter CTkScrollableFrame approach but with the container or parent frame beeing the master. Therefore it would also not work if added directly to a notebook. So as acw1668 said: maybe one has to take a compromise here

TomSchimansky solved this in his customtkinter CTkScrollableFrame by making his class the acutal inner Frame and first creating a parent Frame and Canvas to wrap itself.
Take a look at this extract from its init method:
def __init__(self, master: Any, width: int = 200, height: int = 200, ... ):
    ...
    # first creating parent frame and canvas
    self._parent_frame = CTkFrame(master=master, width=0, height=0, corner_radius=corner_radius,
                                  border_width=border_width, bg_color=bg_color, fg_color=fg_color, border_color=border_color)
    self._parent_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master=self._parent_frame, highlightthickness=0)
    ...
    # then creating the "actual class frame" that is represented by self, setting its master to the parent canvas
    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master=self._parent_canvas, highlightthickness=0)
    ...

Please note that you then have to overwrite all the methods like pack and grid for your frame class to target the parent instead of the inner frame like:
def pack(self, **kwargs):
    self._parent_frame.pack(**kwargs)

Also the scaling etc. are a little hacky but you should be able to adapt his class to your desire easily.
UPDATE:

This looks like a bad idea because it means overwriting all methods related to pack, grid and place, and I don't know all of these methods. In addition to this, it doesn't work when using a Notebook, for example: notebook.add(scroll_frame) should add the container. Who knows in how many cases such malfunctions can happen?

So here is the full translated class with usage demo:
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import sys


class ScrollableFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    """Adaptation of TomSchimansky CTkScrollableFrame logic, but in 'plain' tkinter"""
    def __init__(self, master, width: int = 200, height: int = 200, border_width=None,
                 bg_color=None, fg_color=None, border_color=None,
                 scrollbar_fg_color=None, scrollbar_button_color=None, scrollbar_button_hover_color=None,
                 label_fg_color=None, label_text_color=None, label_text: str = "", label_font=None,
                 label_anchor: str = "center", orientation: str = "vertical"):

        self._orientation = orientation

        # dimensions independent of scaling:
        # _desired_width and _desired_height, represent desired size set by width and height
        self._desired_width = width
        self._desired_height = height

        self._parent_frame = tkinter.Frame(master=master, width=0, height=0,
                                           border_width=border_width, bg=bg_color, fg=fg_color,
                                           border_color=border_color)
        self._parent_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master=self._parent_frame, highlightthickness=0)
        self._set_scroll_increments()

        self._scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(master=self._parent_frame, orient=self._orientation,
                                            command=self._parent_canvas.xview if self._orientation == 'horizontal'
                                            else self._parent_canvas.yview,
                                            fg_color=scrollbar_fg_color, button_color=scrollbar_button_color,
                                            button_hover_color=scrollbar_button_hover_color)
        if self._orientation == "vertical":
            self._parent_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._scrollbar.set)
        elif self._orientation == "horizontal":
            self._parent_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._scrollbar.set)

        self._label_text = label_text
        self._label = tkinter.Label(self._parent_frame, text=label_text, anchor=label_anchor, font=label_font,
                                    text_color=label_text_color, fg_color=label_fg_color)

        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master=self._parent_canvas, highlightthickness=0)

        self._create_grid()

        self._parent_canvas.configure(width=self._desired_width, height=self._desired_height)

        self.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self._parent_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._parent_canvas.bbox("all")))
        self._parent_canvas.bind("<Configure>", self._fit_frame_dimensions_to_canvas)
        self.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._mouse_wheel_all, add="+")
        self.bind_all("<KeyPress-Shift_L>", self._keyboard_shift_press_all, add="+")
        self.bind_all("<KeyPress-Shift_R>", self._keyboard_shift_press_all, add="+")
        self.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Shift_L>", self._keyboard_shift_release_all, add="+")
        self.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Shift_R>", self._keyboard_shift_release_all, add="+")
        self._create_window_id = self._parent_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self, anchor="nw")

        tkinter.Frame.configure(self, bg=self._parent_frame.cget("bg"))
        self._parent_canvas.configure(bg=self._parent_frame.cget("bg"))

        self._shift_pressed = False

    def _create_grid(self):
        border_spacing = 5

        if self._orientation == "horizontal":
            self._parent_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self._parent_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self._parent_canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=border_spacing, pady=(border_spacing, 0))
            self._scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=border_spacing)

            if self._label_text is not None and self._label_text != "":
                self._label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=border_spacing, pady=border_spacing)
            else:
                self._label.grid_forget()

        elif self._orientation == "vertical":
            self._parent_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self._parent_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self._parent_canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=(border_spacing, 0), pady=border_spacing)
            self._scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", pady=border_spacing)

            if self._label_text is not None and self._label_text != "":
                self._label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew", padx=border_spacing, pady=border_spacing)
            else:
                self._label.grid_forget()

    def _set_dimensions(self, width=None, height=None):
        if width is not None:
            self._desired_width = width
        if height is not None:
            self._desired_height = height

        self._parent_canvas.configure(width=self._desired_width, height=self._desired_height)

    def configure(self, **kwargs):
        if "width" in kwargs:
            self._set_dimensions(width=kwargs.pop("width"))

        if "height" in kwargs:
            self._set_dimensions(height=kwargs.pop("height"))

        if "border_width" in kwargs:
            self._parent_frame.configure(border_width=kwargs.pop("border_width"))
            self._create_grid()

        if "fg_color" in kwargs:
            self._parent_frame.configure(fg=kwargs.pop("fg_color"))

            tkinter.Frame.configure(self, bg=self._parent_frame.cget("bg"))
            self._parent_canvas.configure(bg=self._parent_frame.cget("bg"))

            for child in self.winfo_children():
                if isinstance(child, tkinter.Tk):
                    child.configure(bg=self._parent_frame.cget("fg"))

        if "scrollbar_fg_color" in kwargs:
            self._scrollbar.configure(fg_color=kwargs.pop("scrollbar_fg_color"))

        if "scrollbar_button_color" in kwargs:
            self._scrollbar.configure(button_color=kwargs.pop("scrollbar_button_color"))

        if "scrollbar_button_hover_color" in kwargs:
            self._scrollbar.configure(button_hover_color=kwargs.pop("scrollbar_button_hover_color"))

        if "label_text" in kwargs:
            self._label_text = kwargs.pop("label_text")
            self._label.configure(text=self._label_text)
            self._create_grid()

        if "label_font" in kwargs:
            self._label.configure(font=kwargs.pop("label_font"))

        if "label_text_color" in kwargs:
            self._label.configure(text_color=kwargs.pop("label_text_color"))

        if "label_fg_color" in kwargs:
            self._label.configure(fg_color=kwargs.pop("label_fg_color"))

        if "label_anchor" in kwargs:
            self._label.configure(anchor=kwargs.pop("label_anchor"))

        self._parent_frame.configure(**kwargs)

    def cget(self, attribute_name: str):
        if attribute_name == "width":
            return self._desired_width
        elif attribute_name == "height":
            return self._desired_height

        elif attribute_name == "label_text":
            return self._label_text
        elif attribute_name == "label_font":
            return self._label.cget("font")
        elif attribute_name == "label_text_color":
            return self._label.cget("_text_color")
        elif attribute_name == "label_fg_color":
            return self._label.cget("fg_color")
        elif attribute_name == "label_anchor":
            return self._label.cget("anchor")

        elif attribute_name.startswith("scrollbar_fg_color"):
            return self._scrollbar.cget("fg_color")
        elif attribute_name.startswith("scrollbar_button_color"):
            return self._scrollbar.cget("button_color")
        elif attribute_name.startswith("scrollbar_button_hover_color"):
            return self._scrollbar.cget("button_hover_color")

        else:
            return self._parent_frame.cget(attribute_name)

    def _fit_frame_dimensions_to_canvas(self, event):
        if self._orientation == "horizontal":
            self._parent_canvas.itemconfigure(self._create_window_id, height=self._parent_canvas.winfo_height())
        elif self._orientation == "vertical":
            self._parent_canvas.itemconfigure(self._create_window_id, width=self._parent_canvas.winfo_width())

    def _set_scroll_increments(self):
        if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
            self._parent_canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=1, yscrollincrement=1)
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":
            self._parent_canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=4, yscrollincrement=8)

    def _mouse_wheel_all(self, event):
        if self.check_if_master_is_canvas(event.widget):
            if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
                if self._shift_pressed:
                    if self._parent_canvas.xview() != (0.0, 1.0):
                        self._parent_canvas.xview("scroll", -int(event.delta / 6), "units")
                else:
                    if self._parent_canvas.yview() != (0.0, 1.0):
                        self._parent_canvas.yview("scroll", -int(event.delta / 6), "units")
            elif sys.platform == "darwin":
                if self._shift_pressed:
                    if self._parent_canvas.xview() != (0.0, 1.0):
                        self._parent_canvas.xview("scroll", -event.delta, "units")
                else:
                    if self._parent_canvas.yview() != (0.0, 1.0):
                        self._parent_canvas.yview("scroll", -event.delta, "units")
            else:
                if self._shift_pressed:
                    if self._parent_canvas.xview() != (0.0, 1.0):
                        self._parent_canvas.xview("scroll", -event.delta, "units")
                else:
                    if self._parent_canvas.yview() != (0.0, 1.0):
                        self._parent_canvas.yview("scroll", -event.delta, "units")

    def _keyboard_shift_press_all(self, event):
        self._shift_pressed = True

    def _keyboard_shift_release_all(self, event):
        self._shift_pressed = False

    def check_if_master_is_canvas(self, widget):
        if widget == self._parent_canvas:
            return True
        elif widget.master is not None:
            return self.check_if_master_is_canvas(widget.master)
        else:
            return False

    def pack(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.pack(**kwargs)

    def place(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.place(**kwargs)

    def grid(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.grid(**kwargs)

    def pack_forget(self):
        self._parent_frame.pack_forget()

    def place_forget(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.place_forget()

    def grid_forget(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.grid_forget()

    def grid_remove(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.grid_remove()

    def grid_propagate(self, **kwargs):
        self._parent_frame.grid_propagate()

    def grid_info(self, **kwargs):
        return self._parent_frame.grid_info()

    def lift(self, aboveThis=None):
        self._parent_frame.lift(aboveThis)

    def lower(self, belowThis=None):
        self._parent_frame.lower(belowThis)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test App
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Demo - Scrollable Frame in Notebook')
    root.geometry('500x300')

    # create notebook
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

    # create hello frame
    hello_frame = tkinter.Frame(notebook)
    hello_frame.pack()
    hello_lbl = tkinter.Label(hello_frame, text='Hello!')
    hello_lbl.pack()

    # create Scroll frame
    scroll_frame = ScrollableFrame(notebook, label_text='100 Buttons')
    for i in range(100):
        ttk.Button(scroll_frame, text=f"Button {i}").pack()  # adding widgets directly to the scrolled frame
    scroll_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    # add frames to notebook
    notebook.add(hello_frame, text='Start')
    # compromise of using the _parent_frame when adding to notebook etc.
    notebook.add(scroll_frame._parent_frame, text='Scroll me')

    root.mainloop()



This looks like a bad idea because it means overwriting all methods related to pack, grid and place, and I don't know all of these methods. In addition to this, it doesn't work when using a Notebook, for example: notebook.add(scroll_frame) should add the container. Who knows in how many cases such malfunctions can happen?

First, you could just look at the linked github code to find al relevant methods. Secondly you can add the scrollable frame  by using notebook.add(scroll_frame._parent_frame) but I guess this looks not "natural" to you...

I must admit that except the notebook.add(scroll_frame._parent_frame), everything works as I wanted about this ScrollableFrame. I suppose that there is no way to do this exactly what I expected, then. Thanks a lot. It's a great compromise. (I never use Notebooks anyway.)
